# How to set up yaml fixtures with UploadedFile (e.g. image) files?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, fixtures

I want to set up fixtures for my symfony2 project. I want to avoid [PHP classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309077/how-would-you-add-a-file-upload-to-a-symfony2-datafixture) but use yaml files to define the fixtures. Entities that only store text fields and relationships work fine, yet I do not know if it is possible to add UploadedFile, e.g. image files, this way.

At the moment, I am using [KhepinYamlFixtureBundle](http://github.com/khepin/KhepinYamlFixturesBundle) and am not sure if it is possible to define them via a service call or if it doesn't have this feature at all.

I would switch to a bundle providing the feature.

Comment: Have you try a different bundle ? Like LexikFixturesMapper : https://github.com/lexik/LexikFixturesMapperBundle that provide some classes to easily load fixtures from CSV or Yaml files.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice).

Alice is a PHP fixtures generator that allows you to load **fixtures from PHP or Yaml** files easily and **manage uploaded files**. Here is a snippet of code that loads some data fixtures from a Doctrine Fixtures class:

```
<?php

namespace MyProject\User\Fixtures;

use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Nelmio\Alice\Loader\Yaml;
use Nelmio\Alice\ORM\Doctrine;
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;

class LoadUserData implements FixtureInterface
{
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // load objects from a yaml file
        $loader = new \Nelmio\Alice\Loader\Yaml();
        $objects = $loader->load(__DIR__.'/users.yml');

        $persister = new \Nelmio\Alice\ORM\Doctrine($manager);
        $persister->persist($objects);

        // Copy images into the legacy application
        $fs = $this->container->get('filesystem');
        $legacyPath = $this->container->getParameter('legacy_path').'/web/uploads';
        $basePath = __DIR__.'/../files';

        $finder = \Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder::create()
            ->files()
            ->in($basePath)
            ->ignoreDotFiles(true)
            ->ignoreVCS(true)
        ;

        foreach ($finder as $file) {
            if ($file->isFile()) {
                $newFile = str_replace($basePath, $legacyPath, $file->getPathname());
                $fs->copy($file->getPathname(), $newFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in your data to load in a YML file :

```
# users.yml
MyProject\User:
    user_1:
        firstName: "Albert"
        lastName:  "Einstein"
        username:  "albert"
        email:     "albert.einstein@protonmail.com"
```

More info [here](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/08/managing-fixtures/).

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to manage file upload via alice? It would be nice if you could extend your example to include a userImage.

Comment: You can look at the documentation https://github.com/nelmio/alice#custom-faker-data-providers

Comment: This absolutly does not answer the question.